# URL Rewriting all subsites to main site

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm new with URL Rewriting and dont know how to do this:

All sites after `/ex1` should be redirect to `index.php`

My current script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(ex1|ex2)/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But this will only rewrite `example.com/ex1/`and not `example.com/ex1/abcd`

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close to perfect, try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(ex1|ex2)/? index.php [NC,L]
```

Note: the trailing `$` in the regular expression has been removed. That one was the cause why only the exact urls `example.com/ex1` and `example.com/ex1/` were matched, but no longer ones. The trailing `$` anchors the search to the line end, so the end of the url here. So if there is anything between the last matched characters (the `ex1` or `ex1/` in this case), then the expression will *not* match.

Another more general note: this pattern is only usable withing `.htaccess` style files, but not in the normal hosts configuration. There are situations when such files come in handy, for example if you do not have administrative control over the http server. But in general you should always prefer to place such things inside the http servers hosts configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Reason is that such files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and finally *really* slow the server down.

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me, i will accept your answer in about 10 min